# how do I fetch data from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to load the data from mysql

database connection: (database_cnn.php)

Edited:

```
    include 'database_cnn';
    $query= "select * from all_songs";
    $res=  mysql_query($query);
        $result= array();


     while ($row = mysql_fatch_array($res))
        array_push($result , array( 'id' => row[0],
            'title' => row[1], 
            'artist' => row[2] , 
            'album' =>row[3],
            'lyric' =>row[4]
            )
        );
     echo json_encode(array( "result" => $result));
   ?>
```

the error I get:

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in D:\xampp\htdocs\abc\IPA_3rd\database_out.php on line 13
```

can anyone tell me why am I getting this error? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: `include 'database_cnn';`?? **Typo?** or you meant `include 'database_cnn.php';`?

Comment: you have error in your code, row[1], should be $row[1], etc.

Comment: put $ to row,$row[1] etc

Comment: http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/mysqli-procedural-functions/

Comment: my silly mistake!!! I forgot to do it. thanks @Fred

Comment: @Giliweed No problemo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `include 'database_cnn';` to `include 'database_cnn.php';` // missing extension

It is `mysql_fetch_array` NOT `mysql_fatch_array` Also use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of it

You forgot to put '$' for row variable

```
array_push($result , array( 'id' => row[0],
            'title' => row[1], 
            'artist' => row[2] , 
            'album' =>row[3],
            'lyric' =>row[4]
            )
        );
```

I suggest you to go through the php tutorials first.

Answer (score 1):

```
 array_push($result , array( 'id' => row[0],
            'title' => row[1], 
            'artist' => row[2] , 
            'album' =>row[3],
            'lyric' =>row[4]
            )
```

should be

```
 array_push($result , array( 'id' => $row[0],
            'title' => $row[1], 
            'artist' => $row[2] , 
            'album' => $row[3],
            'lyric' => $row[4]
            )
```

and `mysql_fatch_array` should be `mysql_fetch_array`

and

```
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
```

should be

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
if (mysql_connect_errno()){
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up mysqli with mysql.

Comment: what are the difference between these two? and which one is good for fatching data from database? plz help

Comment: @Giliweed **fatching**?? ? same mistake you made in your code, it's **fetching** ;-)

Comment: @Giliweed http://codular.com/php-mysqli you ar using in your connection mysqli and in the script mysql.Be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

use $row instead of row

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    array_push($result , array( 'id' => $row[0],
        'title' => $row[1], 
        'artist' => $row[2] , 
        'album' =>$row[3],
        'lyric' =>$row[4]
        )
    );`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have time, it would be a good idea to learn to use PDO instead of Mysql who is decrepated.

He is a link to the 
[Doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)